# jQuery HTML Content Slide Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I didn't want to write this Q on here but I decided that enough's enough and I need to ask the community one way or another.

I'm looking for a very simple HTML content slider. I.e. div.classname and anything inside it is a slide. Believe it or not i've struggle big time to find anything that's useful for this.

If anyone could recommend some simple jQuery plugins that can do this to me that'd be awesome and sure save me some sweat and tears.

Comment: Have you tried Google (serious question)? First thing I see is this: http://flex.madebymufffin.com/

Comment: I have, I think I mention that in the above. Nothings quite what I need.

Comment: I have a set markup which is already coded, which i'd like it to work for.

Comment: Are you confused with content slider over image slider ? Get any kind of slider(image/content) if it is image slider and its not sliding on image but with DIV's then remove the IMG tag and write your content in it.

Comment: So why are you searching for plugin if you have custom markup, you can make your own slider. Plugin always work with predefined markup.

Comment: Show us the html markup of your code.

Comment: not posting this as an answer because it's a bit flippant, but I think you should build your own. A little reading on the docs (api.jquery.com) on animations and a bit of clever CSS are all you need to code something basic yourself. Good luck anyways

Comment: How can you expect good answers when you've provided very little information and detail about what you want and why the hundreds of premade plugins are _"not quite what you need"_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) from malsup like so:

```
$(function(){
    $("#site").cycle({
        fx : "scrollHorz",
        next : ".next a",
        prev : ".prev a",
        startingSlide : 1,
        timeout : 0
    });
  });​
```

check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/zLekb/

I know it's got some extra stuff, but I'm recycling this example.